# How to execute excel formula without using sheet range with office JS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office-js, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I am executing formulas with the help of the Office JS API.

For this, I am following the below steps to execute the formula. I am first getting the Excel range and executing the formula in that range.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-ranges-set-get-values

Is there any way to get formula results by executingng this formula without using the range?

Answer (score 0):

Your add-in may react to changing the data in a worksheet. To detect these changes, you can register an event handler for the `onChanged` event of a `worksheet`. Event handlers for the `onChanged` event receive a `WorksheetChangedEventArgs` object when the event fires.

The `WorksheetChangedEventArgs` object provides information about the changes and the source. Since `onChanged` fires when either the format or value of the data changes, it can be useful to have your add-in check if the values have actually changed. The details property encapsulates this information as a `ChangedEventDetail`. The following code sample shows how to display the before and after values and types of a cell that has been changed.

```
// This function would be used as an event handler for the Worksheet.onChanged event.
function onWorksheetChanged(eventArgs) {
    Excel.run(function (context) {
        let details = eventArgs.details;
        let address = eventArgs.address;

        // Print the before and after types and values to the console.
        console.log(`Change at ${address}: was ${details.valueBefore}(${details.valueTypeBefore}),`
            + ` now is ${details.valueAfter}(${details.valueTypeAfter})`);
        return context.sync();
    });
}
```

See [Work with worksheets using the Excel JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-worksheets) for more information.

Note, you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.